# Vba deleting all data

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to vba and have written some code to delete specific data and refresh 2 pivot tables. It works fine when I step through each sub but when I add the module to a button so everything is run with the press of the button all the data is deleted.

Below is the code I have written( might be a bit cumbersome but I am still learning). I Hope someone can help me.

```
Sub Deleteheader()
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub

Sub DeleteColumns()
    Dim wsAvlRpt As Worksheet, wsSetUp As Worksheet

    Set wsAvlRpt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AvlRpt")
    Set wsSetUp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SetUp")

    ColTotal = wsAvlRpt.UsedRange.Column + wsAvlRpt.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
    LastCol = Split(Cells(1, ColTotal).Address, "$")(1)
    For i = 1 To ColTotal
        ColumnName = wsAvlRpt.Cells(1, i)
        Values = wsSetUp.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        cntColName = Application.CountIf(wsSetUp.Range("A2:A" & Values), ColumnName)
        If cntColName = 0 Then
            wsAvlRpt.Columns(i).EntireColumn.Delete
            i = i - 1
            ColTotal = ColTotal - 1
        End If

        If ColTotal <= i Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    wsAvlRpt.Columns(7).EntireColumn.Insert
    wsAvlRpt.Range("G1").Value = "Item Desc"
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
End Sub

Public Sub DeleteStatus()
    Dim wsAvlRpt As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim rngAvl As Range

    Set wsAvlRpt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("AvlRpt")
    With wsAvlRpt
        lngLastRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngAvl = .Range("A2:J" & lngLastRow)
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With rngAvl
        .AutoFilter field:=8, _
                    Criteria1:="Ongoing", _
                    Operator:=xlOr, _
                    Criteria2:="P.Label"
        .Offset(0).Resize(.Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    With wsAvlRpt
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub DeleteZeroInventory()
    Dim wsAvlRpt As Worksheet, wsSetUp As Worksheet
    Set wsAvlRpt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AvlRpt")
    Set wsSetUp = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SetUp")

    cntZeroInventory = Application.CountIf(wsAvlRpt.Range("I:I"), "<=0.0")
    If cntZeroInventory > 0 Then
        Total = wsAvlRpt.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        wsAvlRpt.Range("$A1:J" & Total).AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="<=0.0", _
                                                   Operator:=xlFilterValues
        wsAvlRpt.Range("A2:J" & Total).Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        wsAvlRpt.ShowAllData

        wsAvlRpt.Columns(10).EntireColumn.Insert
        wsAvlRpt.Range("J1").Value = "Available Eaches"
    End If
End Sub

Sub CalcEaches()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Sheets("AvlRpt").Activate
    LastRow = Range("I65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Select

    Selection.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "= RC[-1] *12"
    Selection = Selection.Value
End Sub

Sub AddItemDesc()
    With Sheets("AvlRpt")
        .Range("G2:G" & .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
                  "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,SetUp!I:J,2,FALSE)),0,VLOOKUP(C2,SetUp!I:J,2,FALSE))"
        .Range("G2:G" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = _
                  .Range("G2:G" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
End Sub

Sub DeleteStyles()
    Dim wsAvlRpt As Worksheet, wsSetUp As Worksheet

    Set wsAvlRpt = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("AvlRpt")

    Dim AvlRpt As Range
    Set AvlRpt = wsAvlRpt.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    AvlRpt.AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=Array("7A37", "8A37", "CO07", "CO81"), _
                      Operator:=xlFilterValues
    AvlRpt.CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0).Select

    With Selection
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        If wsAvlRpt.FilterMode Then
            wsAvlRpt.ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub ClearContents()
    Worksheets("CloseoutData").Range("A2:J2000").Clear
End Sub

Sub CopyDeleteAvlRpt()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Sheets("AvlRpt").Range("A2:J2000").Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("CloseoutData").Range("A2:J2000")
    Sheets("AvlRpt").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub RefreshPivots()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub

Sub PivotCopyAdults()
    Dim pt As PivotTable, lRow As Long
    Dim oWS_Copy As Worksheet, oWS_Paste As Worksheet

    Set oWS_Copy = Sheets("Adults")
    Set oWS_Paste = Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "CloseOuts Adults"

    For Each pt In oWS_Copy.PivotTables
        pt.TableRange2.Copy
        lRow = oWS_Paste.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        oWS_Paste.Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        oWS_Paste.Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Next pt
    oWS_Paste.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub

Sub PivotCopyYouthLadies()
    Dim pt As PivotTable, lRow As Long
    Dim oWS_Copy As Worksheet, oWS_Paste As Worksheet

    Set oWS_Copy = Sheets("Youth&Ladies")
    Set oWS_Paste = Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "CloseOuts Youth & Ladies"

    For Each pt In oWS_Copy.PivotTables
        pt.TableRange2.Copy
        lRow = oWS_Paste.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        oWS_Paste.Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        oWS_Paste.Range("A" & lRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Next pt
    oWS_Paste.Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the button running the code as is? Or do you have the button running a macro?

Comment: It's hard to tell which one of these macros are the one causing your issue -

Comment: If I run it directly from the module it runs fine but once I assign the module to the button it appears to be running but the end result is blank sheets

Comment: There are 12 SUB-s in the above.  What is the button assigned to???  Which SUB is executing? (you might add MsgBox or Debug.Print or just trace thru.)   There are 7 Sheets in the above  AvlRpt,  SetUp,  CloseoutData, Adults, CloseOuts Adults, Youth&Ladies, CloseOuts Youth & Ladies .   Which sheet(s) are being blanked.   We're here to help, and would need to be shared some more information.

Comment: The button is assigned to a completely different sub called RunReport which calls the 12 subs above. I am not sure if I did that correctly or not. The AvlRpt sheet is the data input sheet, the Adults and Youth&Ladies sheets contains the pivot tables that are pulling from the AvlRpt sheet, the CloseOuts Adults and CloseOuts Youth & Ladies sheets are copies of the data in the pivot tables. All sheets are being blanked even the data that is contained in the AvlRpt sheet. Hope that made sense. Please bear with me as I am very new to this.

Comment: @Sugahoney Need to share RunReport so we can see what is going on there.